# Unexpected padding or white space at bottom of page causing unnecessary vertical scroll?

Tags: html, css, vertical-scrolling

**Problem**

I have a page set with a fixed header and horizontally scrolling content.

However there is something causing the bottom of my content to expand past what i perceive to be 100% of the screen, thus causing a vertical scrollbar to appear.

I've created a JsFiddle to demonstrate the problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/w7PHL/

Here is a picture to further demonstrate what i mean by unexpected gap underneath the pictureframe that is causing a vertical scroll bar.

[image]

I have set no padding or margin to the picture frame so i don't understand why my content is overflowing causing this scroll bar. There is also no content under the photoframe.

Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated.

**My Code**

HTML

```
<body>

<div id="Header">

    <div class="title">
      <h1>Bass Clef Photography</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="tagline">Passion 4 Live Music & Passion 4 Photography</div>


  <div id="tabsContainer">
   <div class='tab zero'>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="BassClef.html">Home</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
   <div class='tab one'>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Music Gallery</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class='tab two'>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class='tab three'>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class='tab four'>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
      <div class='tab five'>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="members.php">Members</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
<div id="photoframeContainer">
  <div id="photoframe">
      <div class="pics"> <img src="uploads/picture01.jpg" alt=""></div>
      <div class="pics"><img src="uploads/picture02.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="pics"><img src="uploads/picture03.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="pics"><img src="uploads/picture04.jpg" alt=""></div>
         <div class="pics"><img src="uploads/picture05.jpg" alt=""></div>
      <div class="pics"> <img src="uploads/picture06.jpg" alt=""></div>
      <div class="pics"><img src="uploads/picture07.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="pics"><img src="uploads/picture08.jpg" alt=""></div>
   </div>

 </div>


</body>
```

CSS

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */


/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}

*, :before, :after {
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box
}
body {
    line-height: 1;

}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

/*End of CSS reset*/


a:link {
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}      /* unvisited link */
a:visited {
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}  /* visited link */
a:hover {
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}  /* mouse over link */
a:active {
    color: #030303;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 100%;
}  /* selected link */

#header{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    float: left;


}

html{
    height:100%;
}
body{
    background-color:#424242;
    height:100%;
}

.title{
    font-size: 6em;
    color: #FFF;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.tagline{
    font-size: 3em;
    color: #d3701e;
    margin-left: 30px;


}

#tabsContainer {
    position: relative;
    height: 50px;
    width: 450px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#tabsContainer {
    height: 50px;
    width: auto;
    padding-left: 30px;
    font-size: 24px;
}
#tabsContainer ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size:24px;
}
#tabsContainer ul li {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0px;
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-size:24px;
}
#tabsContainer ul li a {
    height: 33px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 17px 15px 0 15px;
    font: bold 12px Arial;
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size:24px;
}
#tabsContainer ul li a:hover {
    color: #d3701e;
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 24px;
}
#tabsContainer ul li#active a {
    color: #d3701e;
    background: url(images/navigation-hover.png) repeat-x left top;
    font-size:24px;
}

.tab{
float: left;    
font-size:24px;
}

.tab.one
{
    width:190px;
    font-size:24px;

}

/*#photoframe
{
    top: 300px;
    position: fixed;
    padding: 0 25px 0 25px;
    overflow: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    left: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;


}*/
#photoframeContainer{

    padding-top: 10px;;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    min-height: 100%;



}

#photoframe {
    white-space: nowrap;

}
#photoframe .pics {
    display: inline-block;
}



#photoframe .pics img {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    z-index: 1;

    display: inline-block;
    height:500px;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
}


.upload
{
    float: left;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

Comment: Just so you know, you have an extra closing div tag at the end of your code.

Comment: So i did thank you, i have removed this now!

Comment: I tried it locally and it works fine, maybe small screen size is an issue?

Comment: @Tejas Patel Is there a large gap at the bottom of the photoframe, causing a vertical scroll bar? I'm using a 23" monitor, so definitely not an issues caused by small screen.

Comment: Please check here, its on my local machine http://tinypic.com/r/2txe/8

Comment: On your screen shot the page is missing a photoframe containing horizontally scrolling pictures.

Comment: That is probably because there are none set locally on your machine actually!

Comment: This fiddle shows my problem [link](http://jsfiddle.net/w7PHL/)

Comment: The gap under the photoframe shouldn't be there as i've set it too min-height:100%; Therefore if everything fits on my screen there should be no Y-scroll bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following elements have `height:100%`:

- html
- body
- photoFrameContainer

Margins and padding are not calculated within the height, so 100% + margin + padding is what you see. Here is what the spec says:

> For absolutely positioned elements, the used values of the vertical dimensions must satisfy this constraint:
>
> 'top' + 'margin-top' + 'border-top-width' + 'padding-top' + 'height' + 'padding-bottom' + 'border-bottom-width' + 'margin-bottom' + 'bottom' = height of containing block

Since the calculated height is greater than the height of the viewport, and the default stylesheet defines `overflow:visible` as the default for all elements, the scrollbar is shown.

**References**

- [Visual Formatting Model Details: Absolutely Positioned, non-replaced elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-height)
- [CSS 2.1: Overflow](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visufx.html#propdef-overflow)
- [CSS Dimensions](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/css/css_dimension.htm)