# How to stop an absolutely positioned div from stacking over/under a fixed div?

Tags: html, css

**Problem**

I have a fixed header and a absolutely positioned content div. They are both positioned using a top value, and sit fine until the page height is of a height that requires the scrollbar to appear.

The absolutely positioned div then moves with the page and stacks under the header.

*NB: The div absolutely positioned div 'photoframe' must remain able to scroll horizontally.*

I've made a JsFiddle to better demonstrate what i'm trying to explain.

[JsFiddle of problem](http://jsfiddle.net/Le5RE/)

**My CSS**

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */


/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}

*, :before, :after {
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box
}
body {
    line-height: 1;

}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

/*End of CSS reset*/


a:link {
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}      /* unvisited link */
a:visited {
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}  /* visited link */
a:hover {
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}  /* mouse over link */
a:active {
    color: #030303;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 100%;
}  /* selected link */

html{
    height:100%;

}
body{
    background-color:#424242;
    height:100%;


}

#spacer
{
    height:400px
}



#headerWrapper {
    position: fixed;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height:400px auto;
    z-index: 999;
    top: 0;
}


#headerWrapper #header{
    position: fixed;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    z-index: 999;
    top: 0;


}
#headerWrapper #header #title{
    position: fixed;
    font-size: 3em;
    color: #FFF;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    top: 0px;
}

#headerWrapper #header #tagline{
    position: fixed;
    font-size: 2em;
    color: #d3701e;
    margin-left: 30px;
    top: 90px;
}

#tabsContainer {
    padding: 0;
    margin-left:18px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 120px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 18px;
    font-family: "swiss", "Arial", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    cursor: default;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
#tabsContainer ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size:24px;
}
#tabsContainer ul li {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0px;
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-size:24px;
}
#tabsContainer ul li a {
    height: 33px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 17px 15px 0 15px;
    font: bold 12px Arial;
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size:24px;
}
#tabsContainer ul li a:hover {
    color: #d3701e;
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 24px;
}
#tabsContainer ul li #active a {
    color: #d3701e;
    background: url(images/navigation-hover.png) repeat-x left top;
    font-size:24px;
}

.tab{
float: left;    
font-size:24px;
}

.tab.one
{
    width:220px;
    font-size:24px;

}


/*#photoframeContainer{

    padding-top: 10px;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0px;

}*/

#photoframe {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0 25px 0 25px;
    height: 600px;
    top: 242px;
    overflow: visible;
    white-space: nowrap;
    left: 0px;


}
#photoframe .imageContainer {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 5px 0 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden
    }



#photoframe .imageContainer img {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    z-index: 1

}


.upload
{
    float: left;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

**My HTML**

```
<body>
<div id="headerWrapper">
<div id="header">
  <div id="title">
    <h1>Bass Clef Photography</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="tagline">Passion 4 Live Music & Passion 4 Photography</div>
  <div id="tabsContainer">
    <div class='tab zero'>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="BassClef.html">Home</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class='tab one'>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Music Gallery</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class='tab two'>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class='tab three'>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class='tab four'>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class='tab five'>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="members.php">Members</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="spacer"></div>
<div id="photoframeContainer">
  <div id="photoframe">
    <div class="imageContainer"><img class="resize" src="uploads/picture02.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="imageContainer"><img class="resize" src="uploads/picture03.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="imageContainer"><img class="resize" src="uploads/picture04.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="imageContainer"><img class="resize" src="uploads/picture05.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="imageContainer"> <img class="resize" src="uploads/picture06.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="imageContainer"><img class="resize" src="uploads/picture07.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="imageContainer"><img class="resize" src="uploads/picture08.jpg" alt=""></div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: How would like it to work?

Comment: i would like the div photoframe not stack under the header when the browser is resized.

Comment: I'm not entirely certain why you have used fixed positioning on the header or absolute positioning on the content area. The way these are aligned static positioning makes the most sense for both the header and the content to get the intended behavior.

Comment: Do you mean that when you scroll the page, the content boxes go over the title box element? @DanCundy

Comment: Like this - http://jsfiddle.net/Le5RE/1/

Comment: I have used fixed for the header so it is always in view when the absolutely positioned content is horizontally scrolled.

Comment: @socialconquest that is not how i wish the page to be displayed if you look at my fiddle the header stays fixed whilst the content scrolls horizontally [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Le5RE/)

Comment: @Brendan yes that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Given the situation you have two good options and one bad one. The first is to make everything static positioning and give a set width to the container of the images and use overflow:auto on the photo container. That will provide a scroll bar for the div itself like the ones used in stack overflow for codeblocks and such (see your code above). Otherwise, I highly recommend using a javascript or jquery slider. Way easier to implement and you won't have to fight with css every time you add a little content to the page.

The bad option is to lose the spacer and the absolute positioning on the #photoframe element and then add padding-top:242px to #photoframe like so:

```
#photoframe {
position: static;
padding: 0 25px 0 25px;
    padding-top:242px;
height: 600px;
overflow: visible;
white-space: nowrap;
```

}

Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Le5RE/2/). The reason this is a bad option is that you will still have to fight with css if you every have to add menu items or content elsewhere on the page. Fixed positioning really is a nightmare in most cases and mobile/tablet devices do not handle it well at all.

Comment: The first implementation you suggested caused me issues with unexpected gaps on my page, and after asking why here with no one knowing or understanding my question i gave up. [previous stack question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23495977/unexpected-padding-or-white-space-at-bottom-of-page-causing-unnecessary-vertical?noredirect=1#comment36032060_23495977). The second to me kind of feels like being defeated, and the third is going to be a nightmare like you say! Thankyou for your suggestions though.

Comment: and actually your example fiddle still has the same problem when minimised the content still stacks under the header.

Comment: Yeah, my bad. Again, fixed positioning is a nightmare. Here is another example of the first implementation using your original [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w7PHL/3/)

Comment: That is exactly the same as my first implementation, meaning has the same problems. It would be an ok idea but for some reason the page can be vertically scrolled when in fact all the content fits the screen?! Strange. Hopefully someone will know the solution, thanks again though.

Answer (score 0):

Don't penalize me if I'm wrong but, If i understand correctly, you just don't want that vertical scroll bar, so just add

`overflow-y:hidden;` the body class.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Le5RE/3/)

Comment: You can add that line to your original source code, I just built on @socialconquest's Fiddle...

Comment: I would never downvote someone for trying to help me. This solution does work..... until the height of the browser requires the user to scroll up or down to view the rest of the page. try it on the fiddle you posted by making the displayed page part smaller. Thankyou for your contribution though.

Comment: How about if you change the `body` height to `:auto` instead of `:100%` [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/w7PHL/4/)